# Ubuntu command line client for stackoverflow?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, stack-exchange

What command line client for StackOverflow is suitable for me?

Requirements:

- OS: Ubuntu
- support for various StackExchange communities (not only StackOverflow)
- preferably installable via apt
- browsing

  - interactive mode
- searching

  - based on tags
  - based on topics
  - filter based on stars
- create new question

Possible coices:

- [how2](https://github.com/santinic/how2)
- [SoCLI](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli)